# iPhone large upload worries

Tags: iphone, networking, upload

I have an app that styles the user's photo, then saves and/or uploads to Facebook, etc..

My users have asked if they could save/upload to several services with one button click. So I've implemented a dialog that lets them choose which services to upload, and once you press the button, it uploads to each service, one at a time.

My worry is that if the user selects, say, 4 services and has a full res photo, it could take quite a bit of time for all that data to go up the wi-fi pipe, much less 3G.

Is there anything I should do besides put up a UIActivityIndicator and tell the user where his photo is going...and WAIT? It just bothers me that they could sit there for a long time, waiting for the network gods...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Resize the images I consistently have users uploading photos to my site that are multi-megabyte when all that is needed (in my case) is a 800x600 image.

Comment: Yeah, I do give them the option of different sizes, but not all users know better.

Comment: I like the way Apple does it, not based on file size but on image size, probably best in inches not pixels. Just my bias.

Answer (score 1):

Make the upload asynchronous and backgrounded (using whatever 3rd party library you're using--wait you're not trying to do this with AFNetworking or something, are you??) and then use the Task Completion API to ensure the upload completes successfully even if they leave the app.

I'd go ahead and scale down the image some, too. If they're going to be looking at it on a website, there's no need for it to be full multi-megabyte.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't hurt to add a display string that says "Uploading to Facebook...."  then change it to "Uploading to Flickr...." etc.  You'd be surprised at how faster your app seems if you let the user know that something is going on.  (You could also use a progress indicator as well.)